# Not able to debug ionic 3 app on safari simulator IOS 16.4

Tags: ios, debugging, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am Not able to debug ionic capacitor app on safari simulator IOS 16.4 showing `no inspectable applications`. I tried to add below line of code inside `AppDelegate file`

```
let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
let webView: WKWebView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
```

also added below line of code before return inside `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {` function

```
#if DEBUG
    if #available(iOS 16.4, *) {
       webView.isInspectable = true
    }
#endif
```

After doing above steps it's giving me Application name in safari but target is `about:blank`.
While clicking on `about:blank` it's showing only blank `body tag` in inspector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this to adding few lines of code into `AppDelegate.swift` file in Xcode.

```
#if DEBUG
  if #available(macOS 13.3, iOS 16.4, tvOS 16.4, *) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5.0) {
            if let vc = self.window?.rootViewController as? CAPBridgeViewController {
               vc.bridgedWebView?.isInspectable = true;
            }
        }
  }
#endif
```

inside `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {`

**Note-** This code will only work if you are using `Capacitor`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to touch native files to do this.

You need to use [Safari tech Preview](https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/), not Safari.

You also need to make sure you [turn on debug mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device) on your device.